# Short/abridged story about a colony aboard a space ship

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, spaceship

Here's another possibly obscure one! This story was published in two or three parts in issues of Cricket magazine in the early 2000s. I'm not sure if it was written for the magazine itself or was part of a larger story and adapted for magazine format.

The story involves two cultures floating aboard a spacecraft after, ostensibly, the destruction of Earth. The two cultures exist separately on two different side of the ship and are unaware of the other's presence until the main character accidentally discovers the other culture. The name of the ship is the Boreas.

Answer (score 5):

The story is "**Boo**" by Tom Brennan

> "The woman nodded. “What is your name?
>
> “Boo.”
>
> "That is a strange name"
>
> "Maybe so, but it’s mine" said Boo.
>
> The woman smiled and helped him up. “I am Susan.“How come you
>   understand me?”
>
> "We are not so different," said Susan. "We all spoke the same language
>   once; some of us still remember the old tongue and sing the oldsongs.
>   Now, tell me what happened"

You can read it online here; http://www.cricketmag.com/eBooks/9780812627794.pdf

Comment: Thank you! This was one of my favorites from Cricket. Terrible title, though! Thanks again.